# How to achieve this in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have array that looks like this:

```
var arr = [
{user: 50, id: 70, time: '14:30'}, // ignore this user 50
{user: 70 id: 50, time: '14:50'}, // output this time is higher id 50
{user: 83, id: 50, time: '18:30'}
];
```

what i want as result is to get unique user or id object out of the array by time:

```
var result = [
{user: 83, id: 50, time: 18:30},
{user: 70, id: 50, time: 14:50}
];
```

or

```
var arr = [
    {user: 70, id: 50, time: '14:30'}, // ignores this // id 50
    {user: 50 id: 70, time: '14:50'}, // output this // user 50
    {user: 83, id: 50, time: '18:30'}
    ];
```

then result should bring down

```
var result = [
    {user: 83, id: 50, time: 18:30},
    {user: 50, id: 70, time: 14:50}
    ];
```

further explanation of what i want. Consider obj1 user is 50 and id is 70 and we also have obj2 user 70 and id 50 as long as there is another object in the array that share user <> id - id <> user bring down the recent time value out of them.

Comment: `I have array that looks like this` try again, that's invalid - I'm sure it's `time: "14:30"` etc

Comment: Do you *have* to use lodash? Why not ordinary JS?

Comment: you'll want `array#filter` and `array#sort` methods as documented [in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) - or the lodash equivalents ... _.filter and _.sort I guess (sortBy?)

Comment: maybe pure js but i prefer lodash its lovely and short duh i am too lazy programmer

Comment: I'm very confused about what you're trying to get.  What would be the result with `[{u: 60, i: 50, t: '16:30'}, {u: 83, i: 70, t: '14:30'}, {u: 83, i : 50, t: '15:30'}]`?  Two match on `user`, two on `id`, but not the same two...

Comment: {u: 60, i: 50, t: '16:30'} and {u: 83, i : 50, t: '15:30'} share same value of i. in my case there will never be same value same property, rather will be like that {u: 60, i: 50, t: '16:30'} and {u: 50, i : 60, t: '15:30'} result then would be {u: 60, i: 50, t: '16:30'} i:50 in u:50 so get highest time 16:30 obj

Comment: You want only the highest time for each hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lodash#orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy) to order times in descending order to make sure that we uniquely remove the identical `user` and `id` of each item by the highest order of time. Lastly, we use [`lodash#uniqWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqWith) to perform the comparison.

```
var result = _(arr)
  .orderBy('time', 'desc')
  .uniqWith((v1, v2) => v1.id === v2.user && v1.user === v2.id)
  .value();
```

```js
// First data set
var arr = [
  {user: 50, id: 70, time: '14:30'}, // ignore this user 50
  {user: 70, id: 50, time: '14:50'}, // output this time is higher id 50
  {user: 83, id: 50, time: '18:30'}
];

var result = _(arr)
  .orderBy('time', 'desc')
  .uniqWith((v1, v2) => v1.id === v2.user && v1.user === v2.id)
  .value();
  
console.log('First data set');
console.log(result);

// Second data set
arr = [
  {user: 70, id: 50, time: '14:30'}, // ignores this // id 50
  {user: 50, id: 70, time: '14:50'}, // output this // user 50
  {user: 83, id: 50, time: '18:30'}
];

result = _(arr)
  .orderBy('time', 'desc')
  .uniqWith((v1, v2) => v1.id === v2.user && v1.user === v2.id)
  .value();
  
console.log('Second data set');
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%;top: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter by `id`

```
_.filter(arr, obj => obj.id === 50);
```

You can use core js

```
arr.filter(item => item.id === 50)
```

Comment: note the OP says "by time" ... seems OP wants sorting as well

Comment: @mohamedtebry What to do with time, clearly mention in question

Comment: so basically i want to filter the unique cross values between the object property 'user' and 'id' so that the output brings the highest sorted time out of the two objects that shares same number in user or id to the corresponding existing object within the array